# Importing an html page inside an imported html page

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html5 application that imports one of several html pages into a div through jquery:

```
var path = "../" + folderName + "/" + pageName + ".html";
$("#container").load(path);

<div id="container"></div>
```

This part works perfectly, but now I was recently requested that some of those imported pages import other html pages as well.
 I've tried to use the same technique, but I can't get the pages to show. It's not declaring an error on the debugger though.

```
var subPath = "../" + folderName + "/" + subPageName + ".html";
$("#subContainer").load(subPath );

<div id="subContainer"></div>
```

The code in the subPage is just a background color through CSS. I haven't added anything to it yet.

P.S: I can't use php, the server apparently doesn't handle it

Comment: php doesn't handle it? doesn't handle what exactly?

Comment: I think the person means the server doesn't run PHP

Comment: Where and when is the code above run in terms of what calls the first .load() and when is the second done?

Comment: Yes, I can't use any php solutions because the server doesn't like it

Comment: The 1st load is when you open the main page and the 2nd is only when the imported page is loaded into the main's div

Comment: Your code looks fine, i think the issue is that you aren't waiting for the first page to load before calling the second load, so has the "subContainer" doesn't exists yet, it doesn't work. Put that code in the callback of the first load and it will work i think.

Comment: As far as i know chrome debugger cannot handle scripts that acting at loaded content. So may be here is the reason you didnt see any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `subContainer` code lives inside the code you get in the first `load()`, you will need to put it into a separate js file and do something like:

```
$("#container").load(path, function(){
    $.getScript("path/to/subContainer.js"); 
});
```

By default, scripts do not get executed on content you load in using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
        $(function(){
            $('.a').load('b.php',function(){
                $('.b').load('c.php');
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the page being imported at the end of it insert a `<script>` block with your code inside like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   // jquery code you want to run after all elements on page are loaded
})
</script>
```